# Игнорировать любые запросы

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

Есть сайт example.com
Я делаю запрос `example.com/some_text+some_symbols`

Нужно чтобы после `/` был любой текст с любыми символами и все время открывался файл `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

В корне проекта создать файл `.htaccess` с такими строками:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Но здесь не работает с символами / \ % и возможно еще с некоторыми.

Comment: Поясните, я не понял

Comment: По этой ссылке все хорошо https://test2.rokkido.cx.ua/some_text, но если добавить / , то оно читает как путь к папке https://test2.rokkido.cx.ua/some_text/text

Comment: На самом деле нет смысла делать по-другому. Потому что остальное - обычно маршрутизация на стороне серверного языка. А дефолтная ссылка будет вести на Index, где остальной запрос надо разбирать. Обычно везде делается именно так